# Inputting Birthday Dates without separating them

Tags: c, validation, date

So I'm using C, and I wonder if there's anyway to input birthday dates in an input, example: The input will be like this:

Please input birthday date : 12-05-1994

With validation as well. Is there any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I only can suggest the following

```
int day;
int month;
int year;

printf("Please input birthday date: ");
if (scanf("%d-%d-%d", &day, &month, &year) == 3) {
    printf("Good but need more checking\n");
} else {
    printf("Wrong already here\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int day, month, year;
scanf("%d/%d/%d",&day,&month,&year);
```

After that you can check if its valid for your cause.

Comment: You are wrong. Should be `scanf("%d/%d/%d", &day, &month, &year);`

Comment: But how do you ensure that the person also input that '-' dashes as well?

Comment: @ user3087163 in my case the user has to input it with slashes '/'. But if you replace it with '-'. `scanf()` requests a format for input, so if the format will not be correct it will not get the input. Read here more about `scanf` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this

```
char date[10];
int day,month,year;
int i,j;
scanf("%s",date);
```

Now you can separate the day, month and yeat from that by traversing it and converting char to int like

```
day=(date[0]-49)*10+(date[1]-49);
```

and so on

Comment: There's a buffer overflow issue if the provided string is greater than 10 chars. Also, it is a pain to parse the input.

Comment: but the above way is too flexible which give user a number of way to enter the date like '12-11-1998' or 3/9/1996 or 3\12\2008 etc.

Comment: Yep, also a good exploit that overwrites your return address and executes arbitrary code.. It is _too_ flexible, and that's the problem :P